# Share contact book from java application with CardDAV

Tags: java, android, iphone, vcf-vcard

I want to share with my colleagues a contact book, created with and used/managed by our application. We thought to share the contacts with our phones via `CardDAV protocol`.

Is there any well documented Library which implements the `CardDAV protocol` and help us to make those data reachable from an **iPhone/Android Phonebook** ?

Comment: Did u get any lead into this requirement. ?

Comment: The usage of our internal software was a mandatory requirement, because if we use an external software for carddav we have to mantain and mange two address book and that's not a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, you can look at [Milton](http://milton.io/guide/m2/reference/index.html); for the client, you have to do even more of the heavy lifting yourself, but [Bedeworks](https://www.bedework.org/svn/davutil/trunk/davio/src/org/bedework/http/) looks like it has a decent start of a generic DAV client that can be used for CardDAV access in Java. For iOS you're looking at something like http://sabre.io/dav/clients/ios/